nginx block access to file via configuration
I would like to block download of all files matching *.roots1.gzin nginx.
Working example with a static string:
location /c135.roots1.gz {
    deny all;
}

How do I have to adjust this to have a wildcard instead of c135.?

Use regex location for this: location ~ \.roots1\.gz$ { deny all; }. For case-insensitive matching use ~* instead of ~.

The simplest method would be as follows.
location ~\.roots1\.gz$ {
     deny all;
}

If you want to learn more about NginX Location Blocks & RegEx Patterns, you
may want to review the following Guide.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59846239/2649063

There is no sence to use both deny all; and return 404;. Your example will always return 404 Not Found HTTP response code during the NGX_HTTP_REWRITE_PHASE request processing phase, deny all; directive won't be processed at all. Without return directive, it will return 403 Access Denied HTTP response code during the later NGX_HTTP_ACCESS_PHASE (this means location ... { return 403; } and location ... { deny all; } are equal (well, the first one will be processed slightly faster)).

The second example is almost equal to the first one, except slightly less effective regex (no sence in .* here) and completely unnecessary capture group (allocating resources to create $1 variable that will never be used).

Yes, you are correct. I actually meant to remove the 404 reference. Thanks for pointing that out.

The second example is just that, another RegEx Example. However, I agree that it's unnecessary, as the link should suffice.

I solved it like that:
location ~* /c([0-9]*).roots1.gz {
    deny all;
}


Just FYI - dot character, unless being escaped (\.), means "any character" with PCRE syntax, making your regular expression slightly less effective.

Agreed. You can also test your RegEx Patterns, via this online tool. https://nginx.viraptor.info/
